# Как же все-таки правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Говорят, что "красота радует только тогда, когда ей (ею) можно с кем-то поделиться". Так все-таки, "ей" или "ею"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, как по правилам, но по смыслу мне больше нравится "ею". Иначе можно запутаться в том, кто является действующим лицом. "Ей можно" звучит как разрешение ей, а не нам. Конечно, для "красоты" это не актуально, она не является одушевленным объектом. Но все-таки фраза с "ей" заставила бы меня "споткнуться", подумать.